# In Swift, can one use a string to access a struct property?

Tags: swift, struct

I have a struct and I would like to know if I can access variables using bracket syntax. Here is my struct:

```
import UIKit

public struct Pixel {
    public var value: UInt32
    public var red: UInt8
    public var green: UInt8
    public var blue: UInt8
    public var alpha: UInt8
}

public struct RGBAImage {
    public var pixels: [ImageProcessor_Sources.Pixel]
    public var width: Int
    public var height: Int
    public init?(image: UIImage)
    public func toUIImage() -> UIImage?
}
```

I would like to access the variable like so `pixel["red"]`, as opposed to `pixel.red`

```
var image = RGBAImage(image: image!)!
var pixel = image.pixels[index]
pixel["red"] = 255 // as opposed to pixel.red
```

Is there any way to do this in Swift?

Comment: No you can't (unless you create a dictionary for the components or a custom subscription logic). What's the benefit of string subscription? Literal strings are always error-prone.

Comment: what should happen in case of `pixel["aosiubd"]`?

Comment: Well, I am trying to keep things DRY. I agree things will be more error prone, but I would like to be able to pass a string into a function and use that as the lookup, similar to a python dictionary key. I now have to write this peice of code for the RED, GREEN and BLUE channels: `pixel.red = UInt8(max(0, min(255, rgbArray[0] + diff*intensity)))`

Comment: "I would like to be able to pass a string into a function and use that as the lookup, similar to a python dictionary key" Then use a dictionary, not a struct.

Comment: Thanks @matt will do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think string-based access like this is good Swift style. [vadian shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285637/) how it can be done, but to dynamically get and set members like this, it would be best to use [the built-in keypath functionality](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md):

```
let redChannel = pixel[keyPath: \.red]
pixel[keyPath: \.green] = 0xB5
```

Another option (more relevant prior to Swift 4) would be to use an enum to define the keys:

```
enum Component
{
    case red
    case green
    case blue
    case alpha
}
```

Then adapt the `subscript` function that vadian demonstrated to accept `Pixel.Component` instead of `String`.

This has a significant advantage in that you can no longer pass an invalid key.

Based on your definition:

```
public extension Pixel
{
    public enum Component
    {
        case red, blue, green, alpha
    }

    public subscript(key: Component) -> UInt8
    {
        get
        {
            switch key {
                case .red: return self.red
                case .green: return self.green
                case .blue: return self.blue
                case .alpha: return self.alpha
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch key {
                case .red: self.red = newValue
                case .green: self.green = newValue
                case .blue: self.blue = newValue
                case .alpha: self.alpha = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var pxl = Pixel(value: 0xFEEDFACE, red: 0xFE, green: 0xED, blue: 0xFA, alpha: 0xCE)
let redChannel = pxl[.red]
print(redChannel)
pxl[.green] = 0xB5
print(pxl)
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh if you could demonstrate adding subscript to accept PixelComponent instead of String I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: It's a straightforward changeover from vadian's code; I've added it for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is not a Swift feature, unless you use subscripting (as vadian has explained). If you want something that supplies subscripting automatically, use a dictionary. Otherwise, if you really want true introspection, use Cocoa — use a class derived from NSObject instead of a struct, and employ key-value coding.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun and to show that it is possible, but it's ugly

```
public struct Pixel {
  public var value: UInt32
  public var red: UInt8
  public var green: UInt8
  public var blue: UInt8
  public var alpha: UInt8

  subscript(key: String) -> UInt8 {
    get {
      switch key {
      case "red": return self.red
      case "green": return self.green
      case "blue": return self.blue
      case "alpha": return self.alpha
      default: fatalError("Invalid key")
      }
    }
    set {
      switch key {
      case "red": self.red = newValue
      case "green": self.green = newValue
      case "blue": self.blue = newValue
      case "alpha": self.alpha = newValue
      default: fatalError("Invalid key")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If OP is looking for a cleaner alternative, there is a pod that extends KVC to native Swift structs:

https://github.com/bradhilton/SwiftKVC