# Is there a way to sort an Array Struct with variable parameters?

Tags: swift, sorting

I need to sort an array based on user choice but I don't know how to make the sort declaration variable.

I am sorting an array struct with 16 columns and 100 records.  I need to assign variables to which columns need to be sorted and subsorted and have an option of ascending or descending.  I am able to sort it, but not change the sort choices without making hundreds of if statements.

```
struct arrayStruct {
    var stringV : String!
    var intV : Int!
    var dateV : Date!
    var costV : Float!
    var stringD : String!
}
var newArray = [arrayStruct]()
newArray.sort(by: {($0.stringV, $0.dateV) < ($1.stringV, $1.dateV)}) // This works.

// I want to do this:

let choice = stringV // Error - Use of unresolved identifyer 'StringV'
let order = 0  // How to make this numeric type good after $ ??

newArray.sort(by: {($order.choice, $0.dateV) < ($1.stringV, $1.dateV)}) // So, this doesn't work. Both order and choice are invalide
```

Comment: `arrayStruct` should be `ArrayStruct`

Comment: check this answer - might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285397/in-swift-can-one-use-a-string-to-access-a-struct-property

Comment: check https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-power-of-key-paths-in-swift/ (specifically `extension Sequence {
    func sorted<T: Comparable>...`

Comment: I think you need to decrease the number of sort options here to make this solvable

Comment: The swiftbysundell link looks promising.  Will need to study a bit.  Thx